# How to create the below model drop down in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]

I am just learning .net and i wonder if it is possible to create drop lists like the one shown above or having a list type item where if + is pressed the item is expanded and when - is pressed again it minimizes.
!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using:

1 . [ASP.Net Ajax Accordion Control](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Accordion/Accordion.aspx)

The Accordion is a web control that allows you to provide multiple panes and display them one at a time. It is like having several CollapsiblePanels where only one can be expanded at a time. The Accordion is implemented as a web control that contains AccordionPane web controls. Each AccordionPane control has a template for its Header and its Content. We keep track of the selected pane so it stays visible across postbacks.

2 .  [ASP.Net MultiView Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227665%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

The MultiView and View Web server controls act as containers for other controls and markup, and provide a way for you to easily present alternate views of information.

You can use the MultiView and View controls to perform tasks such as the following:

Provide alternate sets of controls based on user choice or other conditions. For example, you might allow users to select from a list of feeds, each of which is configured in a separate View control. You can then display the View control that contains the user's choice of feeds. You can use the MultiView and View controls as an alternative to creating multiple Panel controls.

Create a multi-page form. The MultiView and View controls can provide behavior that is similar to the Wizard control. The Wizard control is particularly suited to creating forms that users fill in step by step. The Wizard control also includes support for more built-in UI elements, such as a header and footer, for Previous and Next buttons, and for templates. You might use a MultiView control in place of a Wizard if you wanted to create a display that changed based on condition (rather than sequentially), or if you did not need the extra features supported by the Wizard control.

Comment: I used accordion and it is working successfully now. Is it possible to make the data in it editable? Bcoz i also want to some times edit the data and save in the database. Just like i've shown in second picture

Answer (score 0):

You should read about `TreeView` Structure.

[Read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4fz6xk2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok.. so we call it tree view structure. Thank you. I will try it

Comment: I think tree view doesn't suit my idea of doing. Please refer my modified question and can u give me any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in your code behind, but I would suggest looking into using a jQuery plugin for this. Dependent on which one you want, you will just need to render the contents, then have the plugin make it pretty :)

I always like using : http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/